# Error when updating plugins by FTP "Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content)."

Tags: plugins, updates

I run apache2 on Ubuntu, i'm sure there is a configuration or permission problem causing this. When I attempt to update plugins through the admin control panel, after I enter the FTP login/pass and click Proceed. I get the error "Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content)."

And wp-content does exist and have proper permissions from the default install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using code from [this post on WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-plugin-unable-to-locate-wordpress-content-directory-wp-content?replies=11#post-1329826)

Place this into my wp-config.php file

```
if(is_admin()) {
    add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
    define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
}
```

Comment: This code help to me, but I placed it to functions.php in my theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP user account likely does not have access to the wp-content directory.  Are you able to access wp-content using an FTP client with the same user account?

Another solution is to change the owner of wp-content to www-data.  You can do this from the command line by running `chown www-data:www-data wp-content/ -R`

Comment: Yes I am able to FTP in with that account and view the files. I tried changing owner as you suggested for that directed recursive but still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing ownership via SSH or sFTP.

Here is the command: `chown -R username *`

replace username with your actual primary username that you use to login to your cPanel or FTP.

Once you have done this please change the permission of your wp-content as mentiones by @Chris_O

Answer (score -2):

What resolved for me on Lubuntu 14 was the following:

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html -R
```